# How do I access the same bucket using multiple domains on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to parallelize requests to the resources stored on Amazon's S3 service by accessing them with different domains.  I realize that I could just make multiple buckets and make sure the content is always the same.  This is annoying however.  Everytime I upload something, I have to do it 5 times.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do this. S3 should handle many download requests at once. If you need more than that, then use cloud front, which gets the files closer to your clients.

If by 'parallelize requests' you mean something else, then please elaborate.

Comment: I believe @user205865 is referring to browsers' limits on simultaneous connections from a single domain. So while S3 certainly can handle multiple downloads, the browser may be able to perform more downloads concurrently if the resources are served from multiple domains.